# Add Notificatoin Through REST API

Tags: yammer

In my application, I need to be able to add custom notifications to Yammer.  Is there an undocumented way to add a notification through the Yammer Notifications REST API?

Answer (score 0):

Notifications are sent when specific actions in Yammer are triggered, like when a message is received for a user a push notification will be sent to that user. There is no ability to manually generate push notifications for arbitrary events.